# Run javascript code if specific select options are chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have multiple state codes as conditional options not just "C".
But i don't need all of the options, because this code should appear only with some of the options, not all.

So where it says `var stateCode = 'C';` i need to have something like: **'C','D','G','K'**.

Thanks!

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // Set the state code (That will display the message)
        var stateCode = 'C';

        $('select#billing_state').change(function(){

            selectedState = $('select#billing_state').val();

            if( selectedState == stateCode ){
                $('.shipping-notice').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.shipping-notice').hide();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Update:
Here is the html code.. with only 3 options as example.
I need the code to work only with option C and B but not K.

```
<select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" class="state_select select2-hidden-accessible" autocomplete="address-level1" data-placeholder="Elige una opción…" data-input-classes="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="C">Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>
<option value="B">Buenos Aires</option>
<option value="K">Catamarca</option>

</select>
```

Comment: I have a select dropdown in the woocommerce checkout fields. When you select the state, it takes its option value which is a letter. The code works good, but it is only working if I select one specific state. The selectable values are 25, and i need to show a message only if i select any of 23 of those options. Because there are 2 that should not show the message.

Comment: Do you mean like `if(!['A', 'B' /* The two options you want to exclude */].includes(selectedState) )`?

Comment: @MisterJojo I updated the question with the html code.

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx If excluding is possible, i think it would be a valid option I guess. It's just I don´t understand javascript, that's why I ask for help. If anyone can complete the code for me, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array of all the options for which you want the code to work.
Then you can check whether the selected option is correct using [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // Set the state code (That will display the message)
        var stateCodes = ['C', 'B'];

        $('select#billing_state').change(function(){

            selectedState = $('select#billing_state').val();

            if(stateCodes.includes(selectedState)){
                $('.shipping-notice').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.shipping-notice').hide();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't work, and it also duplicates the checkout form completely :(

Comment: @Voltaki I made a spelling mistake. It is includes not include. Can you please try again? Comment if the issue remains

Comment: I don't know why, my answer giving thanks to you disappeared. I just wanted to say thank you again!